# Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with parent-child hierarchy.

```
Id  ParentId
-----------------------------------
1   1  -- root node
2   1  -- 1st level child
3   1  -- 1st level child
4   2  -- 2nd level child (there can be any number of child levels)
5   5  -- root node
6   5  -- 1st level child
```

I would like to add a new column to this table, called `sortindex`. Each level of child nodes under a parent should have their own sort indexes. For example, 1st level child nodes will have their own `sortindex`.

```
id   parentid   sortindex
-------------------------
2       1          1
3       1          2
```

Similarly, root nodes will have their own set of `sortindex` etc.

The table with sort indexes should look like this:

```
Id  ParentId SortIndex
----------------------
1   1         1
2   1         1
3   1         2
4   2         1
5   5         2
6   5         1
```

Right now, I have just added the `sortindex` column with default value 0, but 
I would like to use a stored procedure to update each record's `sortindex`. So it should be calculating each record's `sortindex` and updating it.

How can this be achieved? Thanks!

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sorry about that, I am using sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this useful.?

```
Create table #tab1(id int, parentId int)

insert into #tab1
SELECT 1,1  Union All
SELECT 2,1  Union All
SELECT 3,1  Union All
SELECT 4,2  Union All
SELECT 5,5  Union All
SELECT 6,5 


ALTER TABLE #tab1
ADD sortindex int


;with cte
AS
(
    SELECT id,ParentId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by id)sortindex from #tab1 where id=ParentId
    Union ALL
    Select id,ParentId ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by Parentid order by id)   from #tab1 where id!=ParentId

)

UPDATE t
SET t.sortindex=cte.sortindex
FROM #tab1 t
JOIN cte ON t.id=cte.id 

Select * from #tab1

Drop table #tab1
```